# How does Hinduism explain extinction of species?

Tags: science

[Extinction of species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_extinct_species) is no myth and it is not a theory like Evolution which couldn't be verified at present, as many species becoming extinct day by day. How Hinduism explains this? What if a widely discussed and important animals in Hinduism (like the [spotted deer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31783/does-vedic-karma-yield-fruit-in-foreign-countries-will-it-give-adverse-results/31831#31831), through which only we can identify the land where Vedic Dharma prevails) become extinct?

Comment: There are Pralayas every Manvantara, so some animals will go extinct. Also, I think Brahman makes sure some animals don't go extinct, like the spotted deer, to allow Dharma to continue.

Comment: Also, the Soma plant is now extinct, but the Vedas allow some substitutes. Perhaps there is a substitute for the spotted deer, I'm not sure.

Comment: How is this related to Hinduism? This is like asking: How does Hinduism explain The Big Bang?

Comment: 'not a theory like Evolution which couldn't be verified at present' - in Science, theory is something which explains a fact, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_as_fact_and_theory#Theory).

Comment: @sv. I have already read that and the mainstream argument against evolution is that "has anyone witnessed the happening of evolution(one species changing into another)?" For this evolution supporters don't have any convincing answer.

Comment: @NaveenKick "has anyone witnessed the happening of evolution (one species changing into another)?" - no one with a proper science background asks such questions. There is no "[Crocoduck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocoduck)". Check [this](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20160323-the-unique-mosquito-that-lives-in-the-london-underground).

Comment: @sv. I am not speaking about transitional fossils here.